# $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin(2^nx)}{2^{cn}}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin(2^nx)}{2^{cn}}~,~~~~~~~~0<c\le1$$

I can prove that this function is continuous on real line, 
but can't prove that it is not differentiable on every point of real line. 
I wanna know how to prove it is not differentiable on every point of real line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look what happens when you try to compute the derivative of this function at $ x = 0 $.  You get a non-converging sum.  You can then formalize this by showing that the difference quotients $ h^{-1} (f(h)-f(0)) $ do not converge.  For that, you can use a very rough estimate like $ \sin(y) > y/2 $ for positive $ y $ sufficiently close to zero.  This allows you to get rid of the pesky trigonometric function and work with simple algebra.

Comment: oh! thank you so much.

Comment: can this fact be applied to showing that this function is nowhere-differentiable?

Comment: Yes, but there are more steps.  Expand the difference quotient $ h^{-1} (\sin(2^n(x+h)) - \sin(2^n x)) $ using the trig identity for $ \sin(a+b) $ to obtain $ \sum {\frac{\sin(2^n x) \cos(2^n h) + \cos(2^n x)\sin(2^n h) - \sin(2^n x)}{2^{cn}h}} $.  At this point, you want to fix a large $ N $ and consider only finitely many terms.  Select $ h $ so that $ \cos(2^n h) \approx 0 $ and $ \sin(2^n h) \approx 1 $ and $ \frac{sin(2^n h)}{h} \approx 2^n $.  We have $ \sum_{n=0}^{N} {\cos(2^n x) 2^{n(1-c)}}$.  This sum must diverge as $ N \rightarrow \infty $ because the terms don't approach zero.